# Python: given a 2-D array, check to see if the number of columns in each row are the same without library imports

Tags: python, logic, computer-science

Given a 2-D array named board, write a function that will return True if the number of columns in each row are equal. Make sure the code is able to be used with any input board.

Ex:

```
board= [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,1,3],[0,1,4,2]]
```

is_rectangle() would return: False

Here is what I have:

```
def is_rectangle(board):
    col= len(board[0])
    row= len(board)
    for c in range(col):
        for r in range(row):
            if len(board[r]) == col and len(board) == row:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

but somehow my logic is off. Plz help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the fact that you are returning after checking only one column of the board. This means that you will immediately return True after the first check.

You also only need to check one dimension (your board can only have one length, but each of the items can have different lengths, which is what we're checking).

Some corrected code could go as follows:

```
def is_rectangle(board):
    col= len(board[0])
    for r in range(row):
       if len(board[r]) != col:
           return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

As all lines must be the same size, just compare all of them with the first, like this:

```
def is_rectangle(board):
for row in board:
    if len(row) != len(board[0]):
        return False
return True
```